# how to create a patch

Tags: ros, gazebo, plugin, gazebo-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I'm working with gazebo simulator and I developed some new stuff (sensors) that i would like to share, what is the normal procedure to do that?

To share my package, have I to send my entire gazebo package (with my modifications)? or, should I do something like:

diff -rupN original/ new/ > original.patch

And send only the patch-file?

I ask this because i want to try it in other PC before share it with the whole community.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11116/how-to-create-a-patch/) by [jrcapriles](https://answers.ros.org/users/269/jrcapriles/) on ROS Answers with karma: 370 on 2011-09-05

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While @Lorenz makes a good point about creating new packages, there *are* sometimes good reasons to produce patches for an existing package.

The best solution is to check out a development version of the desired package, then use the diff tool for the relevant version control system (i.e. `svn diff`, `hg diff`, or `git diff`). That produces a patch that is easy for the maintainers to apply.

Using the `gazebo_plugins` package for an example, we first locate the development repository. You can look it up on the package wiki page, or use `roslocate`:

```
$ roslocate info gazebo_plugins
- svn:
    local-name: gazebo_plugins
    uri: https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/trunk/gazebo_plugins
```

Note that this is a package (`roslocate type gazebo_plugins` prints `package`). I recommend checking out the containing stack and not just one package. The stack is the ROS unit of installation, and packages may depend on other packages within the stack.

In this example the containing stack is `simulator_gazebo`:

```
$ roslocate info simulator_gazebo > ~/gazebo.rosinstall
$ rosinstall ~/ros ~/gazebo.rosinstall /opt/ros/electric/.rosinstall
$ source ~/ros/setup.bash
$ roscd gazebo_plugins
```

Test that the downloaded version works unmodified. Then, make your changes and test them.

To produce a patch:

```
$ roscd gazebo_plugins
$ svn diff > ~/my_gazebo_plugins.diff
```

If your patch fixes a bug or implements a generally useful extension to the package, open a defect or enhancement ticket for the containing stack, adding your patch as an attachment.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-09-05**:
Normally, you create patches to contribute bug-fixes or extensions back to the original authors of a package. In that case, the easiest way to get a patch is to use the corresponding functionality of your VCS. For instance, if you want a patch for your changes in package foo, do: roscd foo; svn diff

**Comment by [jrcapriles](https://answers.ros.org/users/269/jrcapriles/) on 2011-09-05**:
Hi joq, Thanks for your answer! It would be nice a detailed example, i used the diff tool but i'm not expert on it! The example would be really useful Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Normally, people don't modify existing packages but create their own packages that extend or use existing software.

In your case, it might be possible to create gazebo plugins similar to that ones that can be found in the ros packages gazebo_plugins and pr2_gazebo_plugins. Other users then just need to download your package and make it available for ROS by setting the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH appropriately.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-09-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SAK](https://answers.ros.org/users/880/sak/) on 2011-09-05**:
I am also working on the package creation. i want to add GazeboRosSonar and GazeboRosIr plugins to gazebo_plugins. and also i have created SonarSensor and modified IRSensor, MultiRayShape(which is present in physics folder of gazebo) and gz, how i would add that to the package.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-09-05**:
I think you should create a new package. Tutorial here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage Have a look at gazebo_plugin's dependencies and CMakeLists.txt to find out appropriate parameters. Also, you need to set a gazebo export tag in manifest.xml, as in gazebo_plugin's manifest.

**Comment by [jrcapriles](https://answers.ros.org/users/269/jrcapriles/) on 2011-09-05**:
Thanks for your answer Lorenz, Do you know if there is any tutorial to create the gazebo_plugins?? Should I create a new package similar to the gazebo_plugin (with my work)? how can i create it? or can I just add my code to that package (with the proper Cmake.., patch, manifest) Thanks!

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-09-05**:
Note a releated question is in flight at http://answers.ros.org/question/2076/how-to-create-a-package-for-new-gazebo-plugins